# A naïve question about computer chips

Tags: fluid-mechanics, rf-electronics

Is it true that computer chips "float" inside of the computers ? Can someone give me references(books, articles, papers...) about that fact ?

Comment: Do you mean physical floating, floating point arithmetic, or floating voltage (as in isolated from earth)?

Comment: Physical floating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they are securely fixed (soldered) to the circuit boards.

If you think you have heard the term "float" with reference to a chip, then you are probably hearing about "floating point arithmetic" which is the process used inside the chip to solve the mathematical equations and calculations we want.

Comment: Or perhaps another meaning for float is floating earth / ground, whereby the mains cable on some devices is only 2 poles not three (extra for earth / ground ), so there is no earth / ground in this setup. Also perhaps float has some physicals / quantum mechanics / quantum computing connotations.

Comment: @therobyouknow so as per the comment by starrise above.

Comment: +1 ah yes - upvoted both